# Chapter 12 Spivak Calculus: Spivak's comments about implicit differentiation

Tags: calculus, soft-question, inverse-function, implicit-differentiation

There is a passage in the Chapter 12 exercises of Spivak's *Calculus* (which is a book specific to  real-valued functions) that reads as follows:

> In general, determining on what intervals a differentiable function is defined implicitly by a particular equation may be a delicate affair, and is best discussed in the context of advanced calculus. If we *assume* that $f$ is such a differentiable solution, however, then a formula for $f'(x)$ can be derived by differentiating both sides of the equation defining $f$ (a process known as "implicit differentiation").

I would like to make sure I am correctly understanding this comment.

Consider two different expressions:

1. $[-f(x)]^5-f(x)=x$
2. $[f(x)]^3-3f(x)=x$

To spare some space, rather than derive statements about these expressions, consider their graphs   of solutions (respectively) when we rewrite the expressions as: $-y^5-y=x$ and $y^3-3y=x$.

[image: First Expression]

[image: Second Expression]|

In the first expression, we have that $f$ is a function on all of $\mathbb R$. In the second case, the graph reveals that $f$ is not a function on all of $\mathbb R$.

If I proceed with the implicit differentiation of 1., then I have:

$$f'(x)=\frac{-1}{1+5[f(x)]^4}$$

If I proceed with the implicit differentiation of 2., then I have:

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{3[f(x)]^2-3}$$

In the first case, there is clearly a single $f$ defined on all of $\mathbb R$ that exists. So differentiating the expression implicitly strikes me as an acceptable 'cheat code' of sorts...to get around the difficulty of isolating $f$ to one side of the inequality.

In the second case, however, it is not apparent to me which function $f$ I am implicitly differentiating.  Is this what Spivak means in his passage when he writes, "**If we assume that $f$ is such a differentiable solution...**"? Under these circumstances, what exactly does it mean, **logically**, to assume that such an $f$ is a solution to the expression and can therefore be differentiated?

It is simply: "Suppose $f_1$ is one such solution to the expression (where $f_1$ may necessarily be defined on a subinterval of $\mathbb R$) and is also differentiable. Then its derivative can be found through the implicit differentiation approach"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what we call a "necessary condition". If $S \implies N$, then $N$ is a *necessary* condition for $S$, because it's impossible for $S$ to be true without $N$ also being true, but if $S$ is false then the truth of $N$ is unknown.

In this case, $S = $ "$f$ is a differentiable function satisfying the given equation" and $N = $ "The derivative of $f$ satisfies the equation that results from implicit differentiation". So if a function $f$ does indeed exist, then it is guaranteed that its derivative meets that criterion.

Indeed, as you show one of the equations does not define a unique function on $\mathbb{R}$, but you *can* define multiple functions on different domains to represent various parts of the relation, and each of those functions will still have matching derivatives.

For reference, the opposite of a necessary condition is a "sufficient condition". If $S \implies N$, then $S$ is a sufficient condition for $N$ because knowing that $S$ is true is enough to know that $N$ is true, but it's also possible for $N$ to be true without $S$. For example, "$f$ is a differentiable function" is a sufficient condition for "$f$ is a continuous function". If a condition is both sufficient and necessary, then we might say that it is equivalent, i.e. $A \implies B$ and $B \implies A$ means $A \iff B$.